Migrate redis string values to redis JSON documents
I'm currently exploring the possibility of migrating redis string value to JSON and wonder if anyone has successfully done so.
I am using Lettuce as the redis client. Right now my object is JSON encoded and stored as a string, since lettuce doesn't support redis JSON yet.
I'm wondering if there is a better way to migrate my data from string value to redis JSON once lettuce release support for redis JSON other than scanning through all of the data, set it as JSON and delete the old key.
